# Invoking synchronous method asynchronously completes task faster than natural async methods

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Sorry for bad title. I am currently learning TPL and reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) blog article which states

> The ability to invoke a synchronous method asynchronously does nothing for scalability, because you’re typically still consuming the same amount of resources you would have if you’d invoked it synchronously (in fact, you’re using a bit more, since there’s overhead incurred to scheduling something ).

So I thought let's give it a try and I created demo application that uses `WebClient`'s `DownloadStringTaskAsync` and `DownloadString` (synchronous) method.

My demo application is having two methods

1. DownloadHtmlNotAsyncInAsyncWay

   This provides asynchronous method wrapper around the synchronous method `DownloadString` which should not scale good.
2. DownloadHTMLCSAsync

   This calls async method DownloadStringTaskAsync.

I created 100 task from both methods and compared time consumed and found that option 1 consumed less time compare to second. why?

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const int repeattime = 100;
        var s = new Sample();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        var tasks = new Task<string>[repeattime];
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < repeattime; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = s.DownloadHtmlNotAsyncInAsyncWay();
        }

        Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine("==========Time elapsed(non natural async): " + sw.Elapsed + "==========");
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < repeattime; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = s.DownloadHTMLCSAsync();
        }

        Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine("==========Time elapsed(natural async)    : " + sw.Elapsed + "==========");
        sw.Reset();
    }
}

public class Sample
    {
        private const string Url = "https://www.google.co.in";

        public async Task<string> DownloadHtmlNotAsyncInAsyncWay()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => DownloadHTML());
        }

        public async Task<string> DownloadHTMLCSAsync()
        {
            using (var w = new WebClient())
            {
                var content = await w.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(Url));
                return GetWebTitle(content);
            }
        }

        private string DownloadHTML()
        {
            using (var w = new WebClient())
            {
                var content = w.DownloadString(new Uri(Url));
                return GetWebTitle(content);
            }
        }

        private static string GetWebTitle(string content)
        {
            int titleStart = content.IndexOf("<title>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (titleStart < 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            int titleBodyStart = titleStart + "<title>".Length;
            int titleBodyEnd = content.IndexOf("</title>", titleBodyStart, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            return content.Substring(titleBodyStart, titleBodyEnd - titleBodyStart);
        }
    }
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q0fzOb) is dotnetfiddle link.

Why did first option completed in less time than second time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't actually measuring anything.

`Task.WhenAll(tasks);` returns a `Task` of the completion of all of those tasks.
You don't do anything with that task, so you aren't waiting for anything to finish.

Therefore, you're just measuring the synchronous initialization of each alternative.  `Task.Run()` just queues a delegate to the thread pool; it does less work than setting up an HTTP request.

Comment: And I add, try `Task.WaitAll` instead

Comment: oh my god. so silly question. It seems I need to call wait like `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();` to measure time consumed...

Comment: @JenishRabadiya *Or*, just use `Task.WaitAll` as Yorye suggested

Answer (score 0):

> in fact, you’re using a bit more, since there’s overhead incurred to scheduling something

Even if you were correctly awaiting the tasks, as SLaks suggested, it would be near impossible to accurately measure this overhead.

Your test is downloading a webpage, which requires network access.
The overhead you're trying to measure is *soooo* much smaller than the variance in the network latency, that it would be lost in the noise.